# Print a java variable with HTML code in a Facelet file

Tags: html, jsf, javabeans, facelets

Is it possible to get HTML code that is inside a bean variable and print it in the Facelets file as HTML code and not as text?

Example:

myBean.java

```
public String getMyHtmlCode(){
    return "<span class="little">Internet</span> 100Mb <span class="little">+television</span>"
}
```

file.xhtml

```
 <h2>#{myBean.myHtmlCode}</h2>
```

But in the navigator appears

```
<span class="little">Internet</span> 100Mb <span class="little">+television</span>
```

And is not interpreted as html.

Any idea?

Comment: Would something like this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020438/backing-bean-property-that-should-return-a-string-with-html-code-returns-empty-s

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki yes, that's my answer as well :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I return HTML from managed bean in JSF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351639/how-do-i-return-html-from-managed-bean-in-jsf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BalusC words from his comment:

> (You) should just disable the default escaping of the text

```
<h2>
    <h:outputText value="#{myBean.myHtmlCode}" escape="false" />
</h2>
```

Just note that this code is prone to [XSS attacks](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: No, he should not escape the text. He should just disable the default escaping of the text.